# Unknown error compiling with bibtex in Texmaker

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, texmaker

I was trying to move my bibliography from bibtex to biblatex, this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[nomarginpar, margin = 2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authortitle,   
natbib=false,    
backref=true,   
url=false,       
isbn=false,      
doi=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[datatype=bibtex]{bibliografia.bib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
La teoría sociocultural subraya la importancia del discurso como un instrumento del pensamiento para la construcción del conocimiento y el desarrollo de habilidades que tiene lugar entre expertos y novatos, así como entre pares, y en distintos escenarios educativos \cite{Mercer95; Mercer2000} por lo cual, el aprendizaje es considerado  una transformación constante de las
prácticas sociales en las que los individuos participan, y con las que se apropian de específicos artefactos culturales o formas de ser;  irreducibles a las propiedades de los individuos. Postula así que el desarrollo intelectual es alcanzado a través del diálogo y que la educación se promulga a través de las interacciones comunicativas reflejando el desarrollo histórico, valores
culturales y prácticas sociales de sociedades y comunidades educativas.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is part of my `*.bib`file:

```
@book{Mercer2007,
    Address = {London},
    Author = {Neil Mercer, Karen Littleton},
    Date-Added = {2014-09-30 01:18:42 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-09-30 01:22:27 +0000},
    Publisher = {Routledge},
    Title = {Dialogue and the development of children´s thinking: A sociocultural approach.},
    Year = {2007}}

@book{Mercer2000,
    Address = {Espa{\~n}a},
    Date-Added = {2014-09-30 01:15:50 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-09-30 01:21:32 +0000},
    Publisher = {Paid{\'o}s},
    Title = {Palabras y mentes: C{\'o}mo usamos el lenguaje para pensar juntos},
    Year = {2000}}

@book{Mercer95,
    Date-Added = {2014-09-30 01:15:50 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-09-30 01:21:10 +0000},
    Publisher = {Clevedon: Multilingual Matters},
    Title = {The Guided Construction of knowledge: talk amongst teachers and learnerse. },
    Year = {1995}}
```

When I compile Bibtex gives me the following error message:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2014) The top-level auxiliary file: prueba 3.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: introduccion.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: Perspectiva.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: facilitacion.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: Metodologia.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: habilidades.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: Actividades.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: Descripcion.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file prueba 3.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file prueba 3.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file prueba 3.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

what can i do to get my references in APA style with biblatex?

Comment: You have specified `backend=biber,` to `biblatex`. Either use `biber` (instead of `bibtex`) or change to `backend=bibtex`.

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using the wrong bibliography backend from that specified in the option of the biblatex package.

Comment: @Guido It seems inappropriate to close somebodies question because he may or may not have made an error -- however, questions about bilatex, biber and thelike definitely are on topic!

Comment: Could you resolve your problems? If not, we would really appreciate a short report on what you did and tried after reading the comments.

Comment: Since there has been no reaction in quite a while, I decided to vote to close this question as off topic because it seems to be about a confusion about backends and how to configure them.

Comment: You have to actually cite references before you process your document with `biber`.

Comment: There were a couple of errors here, it's a pity can't answer this and show what was wrong, because I see more people asking for similar doubts.